# How to apply GAE Application Settings to non-default versions

Tags: google-app-engine, application-settings

Is there any way to apply **Pending Latency** and **Idle Instances** Application Settings to **non-default versions** of an application?

We have both Java and Python versions that must share the datastore/memcache, so we badly want to control these settings for both versions of the app.

If not possible immediately, any idea when GAE team might add Application Setting support for non-default versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these settings are global for your app and can't be setup differently for other versions than the dafault one.
can't really answer your second question. did you try to check out the issue tracker?
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list

you could file a feature request and see what happens

Comment: We've created this feature request and appreciate your starring it if you too need the same control over non-default versions of your app. http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7426

Answer (score 0):

Non-default versions were intended to be for staged deployments to live and are not actually intended to be production apps. Thus, it's not likely that any such request would be accepted by Google. Additionally, it's not clear why you have a Python and a Java version of this app. Your users won't technically know the difference, so in the end it's probably best to pick one platform, Java or Python, and stick with it.

However, I imagine there is something you aren't telling us, so if you do need to maintain both applications for whatever reason, you could use REST to access your datastore from a completely separate app. With memcache, you could reduce any latency by caching frequently accessed data.

This would allow both apps to access the same datastore while also making both apps production apps with their own settings.

Comment: We rely on Python's pil and numpy libraries for specialized computations even though the bulk of our app is in Java.  If you'd find it useful to apply application settings to non-default versions too, please star the issue.   Google supports multiple runtimes in the same app: "Something that's less known is that the different app versions don't even have to have the same runtime! It's perfectly fine to have one version of an app using the Java runtime and another version of the same app using the Python runtime."

Comment: Then in that case your best bet may be to use more of a RESTful architecture and 2 separate appengine apps. REST was designed for connecting two separate, independent systems that are platform/language-independent and allowing them to share data. Your Java layer could make requests to the Python layer and get back the data it needs to do the rest. You'd then be able to manage both layers independently.